# Avoid loop to improve r code

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with million of rows and ten columns.
My code seems to work but never finish cause of the for loop and if statement I think.
I want to write it differently but I'm stuck.

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:5,
                 y = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c"),
                 z = sample(5))

for (i in seq_along(df$x)){
  if (df$y[i] == df$y[i+1] & df$y[i] == "a"){
    df$status[i] <- 1
  } else {
    df$status[i] <- "ok"
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean “never finish”? The code finishes just fine.

Comment: This is just an example, in my case I have million of observation so ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you can replace the whole loop by a vectorised `ifelse`:

```
df$status = ifelse(df$y == df$y[-1] & df$y == 'a', 1, 'ok')
```

This code will give you a warning, unlike the `for` loop. However, the warning is actually **correct** and also concerns your code: you are reading past the last element of `df$y` when doing `df$y[i + 1]`.

You can make this warning go away (and make the code arguably clearer) [by borrowing the `lead` function from `dplyr`](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/742e4166f13effb92b9c61b02e7d02218b8a2361/R/lead-lag.R) (simplified):

```
lead = function (x, n = 1, default = NA) {
    if (n == 0)
        return(x)

    `attributes<-`(c(x[-seq_len(n)], rep(default, n)), attributes(x))
}
```

With this, you can rewrite the code ever so slightly and get rid of the warning:

```
df$status = ifelse(df$y == lead(df$y) & df$y == 'a', 1, 'ok')
```

It’s a shame that this function doesn’t seem to exist in base R.

Comment: One thing is disturbing me, when you write df$y[-1] is equivalent to df$y[i + 1] ? what is the logic please ? for example if I want to compare with df$y[i + 2] ?

Comment: @MostafaRifi No, they are not at all equivalent. Try it out: negative numbers in indices *exclude* these numbers from the result.